# Why does outputting a .rtf file with PHP result in a css file error?

Tags: php, css, file, internet-explorer, rtf

I have the same problem to here, but still not found an answer 
[Php export rtf include css files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22549701/php-export-rtf-include-css-files)
and
http://www.zhgzw.com/524809/codep1/php-export-rtf-include-css-files.

I have PHP code that file_get_contents on an existing RTF file, does some str_replace on known phrases in the RTF document and replaces them with PHP variables.  I then output it back out for the user to download the file.

I find that the problem is intermittent, but when it does happen, the error message has to be clicked multiple times.  All the users on this system use Internet Explorer

The error I get is:

### Problem During Load

Problems came up in the following areas during load:

Missing file: ..Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5UXO0RLDK\style.css

Missing file: ..Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5UXO0RLDK\css/pikaday.css

Comment: can you paste a link to the rtf-file?

Comment: [link to rtf file](http://jonclark.me/csserror.rtf)

Comment: this file looks like the template file, i assume that this happens after you filled the template with data - couldnt find anything weird in that rtf-file

Comment: Thank you so much for having a look at the file roeb.  Did you use any tool/software to find  "anything weird" or just have a look through?  Yes, the <<VARIABLES>> get replaced by variables via a PHP script using str_replace, much like what the others are doing.

Comment: i just used an editor like ultraedit or notepad++ to take a look into the file. add a logging function and log the values when you replace the <<variables>> with values - look if there is something which shouldn't be there, like a link to a css-file